# Flutter CI/CD gitlab - No se reconoce el subcomando "ios" para "flutter build"

Tags: flutter, dart, gitlab, pipeline

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un pipeline en Gitlab para mi app de fluter y ocurre el siguiente problema:

```
$ flutter build ios
Could not find a subcommand named "ios" for "flutter build".
Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

El .gitlab-ci.yml es:

```
image: cirrusci/flutter:stable

stages:
  - ios

before_script:
  - flutter pub get
  - flutter clean

ios:
  stage: ios
  script:
    - flutter build ipa
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME"
    paths:
      - build/ios/iphoneos
      - .app
```

Tienen idea cual puede ser el motivo por el que falla?

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema y parecía ser que necesitaba ejecutar ("top run") el trabajo en un macOS *runner*. Puedes seguir las instrucciones de este enlace para [preparar un macOS *runner*](https://medium.com/kinandcartacreated/setup-a-flutter-ci-cd-with-gitlab-ci-part-1-8d40b7a3b3dc).

También debes asegurarte usar la etiqueta correcta en tu script yml, porque las etiquetas son usadas para especificar los *runners* ya que hay múltiples *runners* compartidos.

Me he dado cuenta de que en tu script, la imagen es muy vieja. Intenta usar una versión de flutter que sea compatible con la versión de tu proyecto.

En el código de mi projecto uso algo como esto:

```
image: "cirrusci/flutter:3.0.1"
```